# Display custom list items in search results for annonymous users

Tags: 2013, search-results, enterprise-search

i have a Web application is enabled for annonymous access and it has Pubishing site collection,
.Limited-access user permission lockdown mode is activated on this site collection.
.a custom News list has list items and allowed ViewFormPages permissions for annonymous users on this list and annonymous users can view allitems page and can able to search the items in this list.

Allow viewform pages on list

```
 $web = get-spweb "http://somesite";
 $list = $web.Lists["somelist"];
 $list.BreakRoleInheritance($true)
 $list.AnonymousPermMask = $list.AnonymousPermMask -bor 4096;
 $list.Update();
```

but how to stop annonymous users not to view of allitems page of custom list and they must search in the custom list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its possible but needs to be configured in central admin first.

1) enable anonymous access for the web application,

(central admin -> web application -> authentication providers -> select default zone and set checkbox to anonymous)

2) then set at site for either site, list/lib or nothing.

(Go to site actions -> site settings -> site permissions under "Users and Groups" click on anonymous access on the ribbon control. Set from the three choices site, list/lib or nothing)

someone has similar issue:

> 1) Created new Web application with OOTB Publishing template
>
> 2) Created Two OOTB custom list and insert the data
>
> 3) Extend the web application(e.g. In my case i have extended for the
>   Intranet zone )( Note:do not select anonymous Access option currently
>   )
>
> 4) deactivate the Lock down feature for the anonymous site by using
>   following
>
> STSADM command
>
> ```
> stsadm -o deactivatefeature -url <anonymous site collection url> -filename ViewFormPagesLockDown\feature.xml
> ```
>
> ( Note : if you have already extended the web application for
>   anonymous access , turned off the anonymous access and then perform
>   the step-4 )   5) Turned on anonymous access on default zone and
>   Intranet Zone form central administration.
>
> 6) Give anonymous user permission for the extended web application by
>   go to the root site -> Site Action -> Site Setting -> Site permissions
>   ->Select "Anonymous Access" from the ribbon and select "Entire Website"
>
> 7) Make sure that the OOTB List inherit the permission from its
>   parent.( if you select Stop inherit permission the result will not
>   come in to the Anonymous search. Note :  you can check this by go to
>   the list permission)
>
> 8) clear the cache and sign out and close the browser and reset the
>   IIS.
>
> 9) Now give the site url of the main site and extentded site in to the
>   content source by
>
> Go to Central Administration -> General Appplication Settings -> Farm
>   Search Administration -> Search Service Application -> Content Sources
>   -> Edit your content source and give the site url for the crawling (E.g. http://mainsiteurl , sps3:mainsiteurl , http://extendedsiteurl ,
>   sps3:extendedsiteurl) -> ok
>
> Note : Give each url in new line
>
> 10) Do the Index Reset and perform full crawling
>
> 11) Now open the anonymous site and perform the anonymous search the
>   result will come in anonymous search

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/29ab357d-74ff-49e2-ad41-5645f43ea4c6/sharepoint-anonymous-search-problem-from-custom-list?forum=sharepointadminprevious

Comment: my web application ,site ,custom list already enabled annonymous access,i need how i display the custom list items in search results page for annonymous users

Comment: what type of site is it? would think that it would need to be a publishing site and not a team site

Comment: publishing site

Comment: updated my answer. bit long but tested on my end and does work

Comment: hi please check updated question here i want to stop annoymous users not to view form pages including allitems page and they must search in custom list.

Comment: go to site action -> site settings -> site collection feature -> enable Limited-access user permission lockdown mode feature . this would stop anonymous users accessing _layouts files like allitems.aspx and dispitems.aspx.

Comment: yes but i need annonymous user also search in this item if he search , example news item , i am displaying in news details page by angular code

Comment: is this a hosted app using angularJS?